# How can I include the value of a button in a form object?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a form with several buttons and upon submitting the form, I want the server side script to be able to read the values of the buttons that were clicked.

```
// someButton is created and appended inside an HTML form element
someButton.name = "foo";
someButton.onclick = function() {
  this.value = "bar";
}

// more code

document.querySelector("button[class='submit']").onclick = function() {
  google.script.run.processForm(document.querySelector("form"));
}
```

In the code above, the element referenced by `someButton` is nested inside a `form`. Also, it should be pretty clear but `someButton` is an arbitrary `button` that is different from the button in `.querySelector()`.

When I go ahead and dismantle the form object from the server side using a code like this:

```
function processForm(form) {
  for (var thing in form)
    Logger.log(var + ": " + form[var]);
}
```

None of the buttons are anywhere to be found. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button value is not submitted with the form. You can pass it as a second parameter to your processForm method:

```
document.querySelector("button[class='submit']").onclick = function() {
  google.script.run.processForm(document.querySelector("form"), document.getElementById("someButton").value);
}

function processForm(form, buttonvalue) {
  Logger.log(buttonvalue);
}
```